# Keep header and footer in place - only scroll body

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with 3 sections that are defined on a shared layout page. I have a Header, Body, and Footer. The header and footer do not change at all. The body holds information that changes depending on what page you are on. I was wondering if its possible to set it up so that instead of the scroll affecting the entire page. . .could the header and footer be held consistently at the top and bottom of the window and only have the scroll effect the body portion of the page.

Here is the current cshtml file for the shared layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Atlas Web Pages</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="web-header">
                <div class="logo-image">
                    <img src="~/Images/Atlas.png" style="float: left" height="125" width="150" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                    <img style="vertical-align:top" src="~/Images/WebPageLogo.png" height="85" width="820" alt="Atlas Logo" />
                    <div style="color:#FFF">*A southpaw's approach to bowling*</div>
                </div> 
                <div class="float-right">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("The Team", "About", "About")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Current Line-Up", "CurrentList", "Current")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Retired Equipment", "RetiredList", "Retired")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bowling Videos", "Videos", "Video")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sponsors", "Sponsors", "Sponsor")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year: Southpaw Web Solutions&trade; - Email: jmilam90@gmail.com</p>
                    <p>Stylized drawing of the god, Atlas, courtesy of shutterstock</p>

                </div>
                <div class="float-right" style="padding-top:13px">
                        <a href ="www.facebook.com/jmilam90"><img src="~/Images/FBIcon.png" alt="Follow on Facebook" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                        <a href ="www.twitter.com/jmilam900"><img src="~/Images/TwitIcon.png" alt="Follow on twitter" height="40" width="40" /></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <table id="logo-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/MBW.png" width="99" height="60" alt="McCorveys Bowling World Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/EboniteLogo.png" width="93" height="60" alt="Ebonite Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/TrackLogo.png" width="152" height="60" alt="Track Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/HammerLogo.png" width="100" height="60" alt="Hammer Bowling Logo" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/ColumbiaLogo.png" width="123" height="60" alt="Columbia 300 Logo" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` both the elements is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed;`. This will fix the element to the page so that it does not move when the user scrolls the page. Also you can add top, left, right, and bottom values.

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That seriously jacks up the formatting when I do that and jams everything together on the left side of the page. It has something to do with `position:fixed;` because if I comment that line out, its back to normal.

Comment: ok I got the placement and width figured out. The footer is still getting cut off at the bottom of the window though. I can't seem to get it to move up vertically and don't understand why the `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` is pushing part of the footer off the bottom of the window.

Comment: nevermind! I figured out where the problem was. I was still using the footer height that I gave it before fixing the position. I had to adjust that.